# Can we apply geostatistics on data which is not normally distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution, geostatistics

If we work on groundwater data, if the data is not normally distributed,  can we apply geostatistics on this data without transforming it to normal distribution?

Comment: Hi Araminta. Welcome to CV. Is there any compelling reason why it has to be normal data and if other wise it has to be _transformed_? In general, normality can be a desirable trait, but lack of it is not a huge hindrance in itself. Please cite your sources that have prompted such assertion, if there is any.

Answer (score 2):

Geostatistics is an entire branch of statistics -- it's all the statistics that are applied to spatial data. Some of its methods may require normally distributed data (see below), but many do not. For instance, kriging is a common geostatististical method and it does not require normal data, as this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging) makes clear.

Are you asking about some specific method within geostatistics?

Re Normality of data requirement: If you apply more general statistical methods to geographic data, I think that qualifies as geostatistics. But even, say, a linear multilevel model does not require normal *data*, it assumes normally distributed *errors*. And, if that assumption is grossly violated, you can use a nonlinear MLM.